# Product of groups with "identified" quoteint.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-group

Let $G_1,G_2, H$ three groups and two epimorphisms $\mu_i\colon G_i\to H$. Define
\begin{equation} G_1\triangle G_2=\{(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2\mid \mu_1(g_1)=\mu_2(g_2)\}.\end{equation}
Call $N_i=Ker(\mu_i)$ for $i=1,2$ and $R_1=\{(1_{N_1},n_2)\mid n_2\in N_2\}$ and $R_2=\{(n_1,1_{N_2})\mid n_1\in N_1\}$. The group $G_1\triangle G_2$ has this properties

- $N_j\simeq R_i\unlhd G_1\triangle G_2$ for $i\neq j$
- $G_i\simeq G_1\triangle G_2/R_i$ for $i=1,2$
- $G_1\triangle G_2/R_1\times R_2\simeq H$

These groups are described in Satz I9.11 of Endliche Gruppen I, B. Huppert. The author calls them

> das direkte produkte von $G_1,G_2$ mit vereinigter Faktorgruppe $H$

This resemble me a sort of dual concept of the amalgam product, even though the traslation would be "the direct product of $G_1,G_2$ with identified quotient". In my research, I ended up with these groups, that I've described only for completeness.
I would be thankful to find some other source in literature, I don't know their standard name in english. Moreover, I can't find the latex symbol used to identify them. The latex symbol for the central products would be helpful too, because I could rotate it.

Comment: [Pullback?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)#Examples)

Comment: I know this under the name ``subdirect product''. To find LaTeX symbols, try: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: \Yup and \Ydown provides the symbols for the groups in this question and the central products. These commands work once the latex package "stmaryrd" is loaded. This package messes up with "mathabx".
Yes pullback is the right concept, usually I don't have my hands in cathegory theory and I didn't figure it out. Nevertheless I wondered if there is a name that doesn't come from cathegories (I'm following a pretty standard group-theoretic approach).